# OpenCV traffic signal recognition error while building

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to use source code for http://moegelmose.com/p10/ for a project. I'm new to opencv and have minimum knowledge in C++. While building I get the following error,

```
 could not convert '0' from 'int' to 'Mat {aka cv::Mat}'
 void hueAdd(Mat image, int value, Mat mask = 0, int upperBound = 180);
```

The code in line 20 is,

```
void hueAdd(Mat image, int value, Mat mask = 0, int upperBound = 180);
```

The function call as follows;

```
void hueAdd(Mat image, int value, Mat mask, int upperBound) {
assert(image.type() == CV_8UC1);
assert(mask.type() == CV_8UC1);

for(int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++) {
        if(mask.at<uchar>(i,j) == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        int result = (int)image.at<uchar>(i, j) + value; // Typecasting to make sure negative results can be saved.

        if(result > upperBound) {
            image.at<uchar>(i, j) = result-upperBound;
        } else if(result < 0) {
            image.at<uchar>(i, j) = upperBound+result;
        } else {
            image.at<uchar>(i, j) = result;
        }

    }
}
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: rather change the declaration to `void hueAdd(Mat image, int value, Mat mask, int upperBound = 180);`  . the whole function does not make any sense without a valid mask.

Comment: @berak Instead you could change the mask check to `if(mask && mask->at<uchar>(i,j) == 0)` than the funtion makes sense without a mask ;). Would actually be the best option as it makes the function more versatile. I Edited this into my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use `nullptr` instead of 0 for `Mat mask`

**Edit:**

Use [`Mat::zeros(image.size(), image.type())`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-zeros) to create an empty mat of the same size and type as your `image`.

Use [`Mat::ones(image.size(), image.type())`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-ones) to create a mask that will pass all the values through

Comment: @mirsoval now i get the same error instead of '0' its 'nullptr'

error: could not convert 'nullptr' from 'std::nullptr_t' to 'Mat {aka cv::Mat}'
  
                                                                               ^

Answer (score -1):

I would change the function to work with pointers to the images:

```
void hueAdd(Mat* image, int value, Mat* mask = NULL, int upperBound = 180);
```

The code of the function would then look like:

```
void hueAdd(Mat* image, int value, Mat* mask, int upperBound) 
{
assert(image);
assert(image->type() == CV_8UC1);
assert(mask->type() == CV_8UC1);

for(int i = 0; i < image->rows; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < image->cols; j++) {
        if(mask && mask->at<uchar>(i,j) == 0) {
            continue;
        }
[...]
```

---

**EDIT:**

I removed the `assert` for the mask and instead added a check if the mask is present. This way the function works with and without a given mask.
If no mask is given the whole image gets processed.